# CFWindow Modal Background Color - ColdFusion 9

Tags: ajax, extjs, coldfusion

I am trying to figure out how to change the background color of a modal cfwindow. Not the background color of the window but rather the color of the main page behind the cfwindow. I want to make it darker than it is.

I know it uses ExtJS so I am pretty sure it can be done but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

I would like to have control over it like you can in jQuery dialog boxes.

I would also like to figure out a way to fade the windows in instead of the way they just kind of pop up. I am not sure if that is possible though.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try  `<cfwindow bodystyle="background-color: red;" ....>`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was meaning the color of the page behind the cfwindow. When you set it to modal it makes the background of the page a light grey. I want to make it much darker.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself on this blog - http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2007/10/9/CFWINDOW-change-modal-mask-color